# AST Transformation in Groovy: Create Macro to Give a Basic Constructor

Tags: groovy, macros, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to make a macro that would essentially expand this:

```
@WithBasicConstructor
class Person {
  private String name
  private String address
}
```

into this:

```
class Person {
  private String name
  private String address

  Person(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name
    this.address = address
  }
}
```

I've been reading through the code for `@Immutable` to get a feel for how it is done.  Has anyone used the new AstBuilder?

Any ideas how to implement this?  Is there a preferred option between AstBuilder for string/code/spec ?

Comment: what desirable properties would this @WithBasicConstructor provide that are not already provided by @Immutable?

Comment: @Immutable applies a large amount of other stuff to a class, other than what I want

Answer (score 1):

You could use (or copy) `@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor` from groovy 1.8.
Regarding preferences... I like the `buildFromSpec`, it leads to fewer surprises.
But I'd suggest you try the `buildFromCode`, test its limitations and quirks, play a little with all of them.